# Razor Pages .Net Core - Passing ID from a table row to a modal popup

Tags: asp.net-core, modal-dialog, razor-pages

I am new to Razor pages so please bear with me. I have a table which is populated as follows on my page:

[image]

Clicking on the last column opens up a modal popup:

[image]

Which has a button to Delete the row that was selected. I cannot however seem to figure out how I would pass the ID of the selected row from the table into the `DeleteSeasonTrip()` javascript function where I post an Ajax call to delete the chosen row.

I thought that I might be able to populate a hidden field on the row click and get it from there but wonder if there would be a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first add css class  "itemfieldId" and id on button that open the model as shown

```
<a  id="@item.ID" class="itemfieldId" data-toggle="model" data- 
 target="#deleteSeasonModel">Delete</a>
```

then add hidden field in modal popup

```
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnselectedfieldId" />
```

add script

```
    $(".itemfieldId").on("click", function ()
    {
        $("#hdnselectedfieldId").val($(this).attr('id'));
    })
```

and now you have itemid in hidden field which you can send

```
    DeleteSeasonTrip()
    {
        var itemId = $("#hdnselectedfieldId").val();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this... This looks like a much neater way of handling it through a hidden input field! Appreciated!

Comment: @Nas can boostrap do it for us wihtot jquerey